# Some files are not generating , while creating a Microservice application in JHipster

Tags: jhipster

Some files are not generating , while creating a Microservice application in JHipster.

I created a Jhipster Microservice application, with MySQL DB, Hazelcast caching, Eureka server, Elastic search engine and Cucumber testing Tool.

I have installed all the pre-requisite before creating JHipster project (Java 8, Maven, Git hub, Node.js, Yeoman, Yard, gulp and Bower, jhipster generator)

But after creating the project, some files seems to be missing (like Gulpfile and Bower files).

Could anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JHipster microservice appliocation has no UI so there's no frontend tooling needed (gulp, bower, ...). The UI is on a gateway which you probably haven't generated. See our [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/), there is a diagram that shows all the elements of our microservices architecture.

Comment: For live reload , gulp is required. Right ? I have included the GulpFile.js to my application and now it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Not at all, a microservice app does not have any js, html or css to reload, So there is no need for gulp serve The only thing that you could hot reload  are java classes and this is covered by spring boot devtools in your pom.xml. In short: the only tool you need is maven.